# Rails with Gcloud ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error. Deployed Version:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When i run `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default`.
Everything going okay
But at the end rails error.

> ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error. Deployed Version:

[image]

Please guide me why this error is

> ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Deployed Version: 20151021t153015.388002942195338741

Answer (score 0):

`Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying)` means that your app did not start up successfully. This could be because of a missing dependency or any other problem that would cause a crash. Please check the logs in the Google Cloud Platform [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Select your project, then navigate to **Monitoring > Logs**. You'll be able to see all of the logs for your project.

Comment: But now my application is runny locally great but not run on VM